# Bat files - Update username password

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, batch-processing

I have a number of bat files in my drive, On a monthly basis I want to update the bat files with new username and passwords replacing the old credentials in each of the bat files. For now each bat file is opened and the credentials are manually updated.

Is there is way I can update the bat files with passwords at once?

Comment: Are all the passwords identified by the same string in all the batch files?  You can look for a string and update it if it is the same string everywhere but if you have different strings, then it is a problem because the program which does the password updates will need to know what to look for in every case.

Comment: Use only one batch to store username and password into environment variables. Call this bat from the others to retrieve the credentials. You will only need to maintain one batch file.

Comment: MC ND - Can you please provide a sample setup ? . Yes all batch files have same credetials

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you like the idea to edit a single file instead of all those batches?

Edit your batchfiles (a last time) and include this code:

```
(
set /p user=
set /p pwd=
)<credentials.txt
echo %user% %pwd%
```

That will take `user` and `password` from a file (`credentials.txt`) 
`credentials.txt` will have two lines only. First line is `username`, 2nd line is `password`:

```
testuser
secretword
```

In Future, you will only have to maintain this little file.

Comment: Stephen - Thanks.I Store the credentials in say "C:\Test" location am I only to edit the line to <C:\credentials.txt ?  Also the credentials file am I to edit it as Ex : user=Testuser pwd=password ?

Comment: no, only the name in the first line and the password in the second line. If you want to have `user=` in front of it, this code does not work

Comment: Pasted bat file and text in same folder. Now it says cannot find file specified...something to do with <credentials.txt line ?

Comment: Should work. Maybe there is a typo in the filename (credentials.txt)?

Comment: Did you start the batch with a double-click? then the workingdir would be different. Put `cd "%~dp0"` into the first line of the BAT. Btw: @foxidrive showed another way to skin this cat.

Comment: Always use `cd /d "%~dp0"` to change the path to that of the batch file. This will work much better.

Comment: I did not start the batch with a doubleclick...I am executing from a new window...Also including the cd /d "%~dp0" does not effect the result..pls help

Comment: Sorry, the only way I've found to get "cannot find" is to delete `credentials.txt` (or renaming it)

Answer (score 1):

In pw.bat you can have

```
@echo off
set "user=myname"
set "pw=apple"
```

and in every other batch file that needs the credentials you start it with

```
@echo off
call pw.bat
```

and you can use the `%user%` and `%pw%` variables in your batch files, and maintain just the one file with the username and password.